# Jmeter not POSTing binary data correctly

Tags: http, jmeter, protocol-buffers, binary-data

I am trying to post protobuf data with JMeter.  I have a Sampler HTTP Request setup with the body as:

```
b''
```

This should simply be an empty protobuf object, but JMeter is actually sending some wrapped version of this:

```
b"b''"
```

I have used Content-Type to be both application/protobuf and application/octet-stream.

Is there a way to get JMeter to post EXACTLY what I give it.

Comment: post your http sampler configuration.